# Parse Server - Adding user to role

Tags: php, parse-server

How would I go about adding a User to a Role using Parse Server

```
(Ex: objectID for user: "oIb528AX98") 

(Ex: Role: "Administrator")
```

I looked through the Parse Docs and there is no example that shows how to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're mistaken, the Guide does show how to add both users and roles to another role using PHP. It just doesn't have its own header. Read the whole Role section here:

http://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/#roles

Guides and API references for all SDKs can be found here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/